# SQL IF [complex condition] THEN OUTPUT NEW TABLE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

I need to output a table containing just one row with "yes" IF some complex condition is met. How would I got about doing this?

The condition is something like this: "if the age difference between the oldest and youngest professors between 2004 and 2008 is at most 10 years"...

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no `IF` in sql. please rephrase you question.

Comment: In transact SQL there is https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717%28v=sql.110%29.aspx  You could query the data into two variables and then run an if statement based upon data in those variables

Comment: How about in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, something like this should work.

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN
    (DATE_PART('year', MAX(Birthdate)) - DATE_PART('year', MIN(Birthdate))) * 12 +
    (DATE_PART('month', MAX(Birthdate)) - DATE_PART('month', MIN(Birthdate)))
    <= 120 THEN 'Yes'
  ELSE 'NO'
  END
FROM Professors
WHERE DateEmployed BETWEEN '2004-01-01' AND '2008-12-31';
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4aee6/9)